# R cut Pretty-print Values Beyond Boundaries

Tags: r, cut

Is there some functionality in R which will pretty-print a numeric vector converted into a factor when some values are beyond `breaks`? The desired input and output is

```r
data <- seq(5, 95, 10)
result <- cutSpecial(data, breaks = c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70))
disc <- c("<30", "<30", "<30", "[30, 40)", "[40, 50)", "[50, 60)", "[60, 70)",
+   ">70", ">70", ">70")
cbind(data, disc)
     data disc      
 [1,] "5"  "<30"     
 [2,] "15" "<30"     
 [3,] "25" "<30"     
 [4,] "35" "[30, 40)"
 [5,] "45" "[40, 50)"
 [6,] "55" "[50, 60)"
 [7,] "65" "[60, 70)"
 [8,] "75" ">70"     
 [9,] "85" ">70"     
[10,] "95" ">70"
```

The base R `cut` function simply turns values outside of the range into unsatisfying `NA`. What function in the R ecosystem would `cutSpecial` be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be `chop()` from my `santoku` package:

```r
library(santoku)
data <- seq(5, 95, 10)
chop(data, c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70))
##  [1] [5, 30)  [5, 30)  [5, 30)  [30, 40) [40, 50) [50, 60) [60, 70) [70, 95] [70, 95]
## [10] [70, 95]
## Levels: [5, 30) [30, 40) [40, 50) [50, 60) [60, 70) [70, 95]
```

If you want specific labels you can either pass them in yourself:

```r
chop(data, c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70), c("< 30", "[30-40)", "[40-50)", "[50-60)", "[60-70)", ">= 70"))
```

Or in the latest version, you can use `lbl_dash()` and specify `first` and `last`:

```r
chop(data, c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70), labels = lbl_dash(first = "< 30", last = ">= 70"))
##  [1] < 30    < 30    < 30    30 - 40 40 - 50 50 - 60 60 - 70 >= 70   >= 70   >= 70  
## Levels: < 30 30 - 40 40 - 50 50 - 60 60 - 70 >= 70
```

There's no such argument for the default interval labels, but maybe there should be.